# How to create a google map popup in xamrin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, render

Am new in xamarin , i want to develop a popup in xamarin forms map. am using this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin to develop the same. am able to design android popup [image]

but i didn't get the same result in ios, [image]

how to get the same result in both platforms .

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue